# No encuentra la función DLL C++

Tags: c++, function

Código que tiene mi archivo DLL:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<iostream>

extern __declspec(dllexport) int test_call(int x, int y)
{
     //std::cout << x + y << std::endl;
     return x + y;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
LPVOID lpReserved
                  )
{
      //test_call(3,4);
      switch (ul_reason_for_call)
      {
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
          MessageBox(0, L"Test", L"Atached", 0);
      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
           //Detach instantly
           MessageBox(0, L"Test2", L"Detached", 0);
      break;
   }
return TRUE;
}
```

Código que tiene la aplicación que hace llamada a la función test_call:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;
typedef int(*DLLPROC)(int,int);
int main() {
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
    DLLPROC HelloWorld;
    BOOL fFreeDLL;

    hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(L"dllmain.dll");
    cout << hinstDLL << endl;
    if (hinstDLL != NULL)
    {
        HelloWorld = (DLLPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "test_call");
        cout << HelloWorld << endl;
        if (HelloWorld != NULL) {
            /*cout <<*/ HelloWorld(5, 6);/* << endl;*/
        }
        else {
            //Always direction memory NULL
            cout << "Problem here" << endl;
        }

        fFreeDLL = FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Tengo una herramienta llamada Dependency Walker que lo que hace es ver las funciones que tiene una DLL y me da estos errores:

**
Error: al menos una dependencia requerida implícita o reenviada no se encontró.
Error: Al menos un módulo tiene una importación no resuelta debido a una función de exportación faltante en un módulo implícitamente dependiente.
Error: se encontraron módulos con diferentes tipos de CPU.
Advertencia: no se encontró al menos un módulo de dependencia de carga de retraso.
**

Answer (score 1):

El código de la DLL tiene pinta de estar todo en la cabecera y esto es un error. ¿Por qué?

- `extern` no se utiliza para esto.
- Cuando la aplicación utiliza la cabecera de la DLL para enlazarse se enlazará con la opción `dllexport`, cuando tendría que hacerlo con `dllimport`
- Implementar la función en la cabecera podría dar lugar a implementaciones `inline` y no creo que quieras eso.
- Cualquier cambio en la implementación de la DLL te podría obligar a recompilar la aplicación y ese es uno de los detalles que se intenta evitar al trabajar con DLLs
- La función `DllMain` solo es necesaria cuando enlazas la DLL en tiempo de compilación, para poder inspeccionar sus funciones. Si enlazas con la DLL en tiempo de compilación esta función es innecesaria.

Acciones a tomar... debería bastar con tocar únicamente la DLL. Necesitarás 2 ficheros:

**cabecera**

```
#ifdef DLL_COMPILATION
#define DLL_OPTION __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_OPTION __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLLOPTION int test_call(int x, int y);
```

Las directivas que ves permiten que la cabecera se pueda utilizar tanto para generar la DLL como para usarla... lo único que tienes que hacer para generar la DLL es añadir el nombre `DLL_COMPILATION` en el *makefile* (o en las opciónes de compilación de VS... dependerá de cómo compiles). En el momento de montar la aplicación no tendrás que hacer nada... si no encuentra el nombre se configura en modo importación.

**implementación**

```
#include "cabecera.h"

int test_call(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Todo eso lo vi en MSDN, pero gracias de todas formas, a la vez le puse extern "C" al header, sino no me reconocía la función, para mi esto lo de las DLL es un gran paso, ayer no dormí bien y no me enteraba de lo que hacia y hoy entiendo todo.

Comment: De paso te cuento que lo de DLL_COMPILATION no hace falta definir lo, hay una variable que ya esta definida de forma predeterminada, llamada DLLMAIN_EXPORTS

Comment: @imgoodik `extern C` solo es necesario si la librería vas a enlazarla con una aplicación en C... En cuanto a lo de `DLLMAIN_EXPORTS`... perfecto entonces, úsala y no deberías tener problemas.... salvo que estés enlazando una DLL con otra...

Comment: Y sin extern como se supone que se tiene que llamar la funcion ? Al menos a mi no me la reconoce como función, que tengo que poner: int test_call(int,int) ?

Comment: @imgoodik podríamos decir que `extern` se podría usar para evitar cargar el `#include` correspondiente. Lo único que dice `extern` es que la función o variable que le sigue existe en alguna parte del programa la cual desconoces... de localizarla ya se encargará el enlazador... no hace falta decir que en el caso de variables, éstas deben ser estáticas.